# Views - field template vs php field

Tags: 7, theming, views

What should be considered the optimal way of creating a custom field in views?

For example:

```
if($content_type == 'article'){
  print 'something';
}
else{
  print 'something else';
}
```

I either create a Custom Text field and write my php code in its template, or, lately, I've started using [views_php](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) field.

The disadvantage with the templates is that if your site is kinda big, you end up with tons of template files that are sometimes hard to manage, and also (obviously) cannot be managed from someone without server access. Furthermore it cannot support sorting/filtering of some kind.
Apart from that, it's "fail safe", it's robust, it doesn't add to complexity via an extra module.

The (possible) disadvantage of the php field is that it's an extra layer of complexity to the site and thus an extra bug possibility.
Apart from that, it's easily manageable and it can even be used for filtering/sorting!

So, what would you guys suggest? What do you usually do in such cases?

Comment: Don't be fooled into thinking 'easier' is necessarily 'better' here. The PHP filter uses `eval()` (which everybody knows is evil and a huge security risk; if you haven't come across that truth before Google it - you'll never use the PHP filter again!) Couple that with the inability to revision code held in the database and there's just no argument for using the PHP filter at all IMHO.

Comment: Geez I feel like I have to go back to all my projects and re-do every implementation/usage of php field now :S

Comment: Sorry that did sound a but harsh, but one needs to be hard-nosed when it comes to security :) If you want to audit what Views you have in the system that use the PHP filter, run this code: `$views = db_query("SELECT vv.name, vd.id FROM views_view vv INNER JOIN views_display vd ON vd.vid = vv.vid WHERE display_options LIKE '%php_output%'")->fetchAll();`, `$views` will contain a list of rows from the main views table, check the `name` column for the view name and go from there

Comment: No need for apologies. Constructive critisism is always welcome. There is learning possibility everywhere ;)

Comment: Also, Clive, I reckon your query wouldn't take into consideration views that live 'in code' i.e. managed/tracked with Features?

Comment: If those views are installed and available on the site it shouldn't matter whether they originated from, they should still be in the database somewhere. I think :P

Comment: Hehe, with all due respect I think you are wrong there :) Ran the query and it only showed my current 'in development' views; A.k.a. the ones not yet tracked with features. Maybe a different query would be required, allthough with a global db search I can only find the views' in question names in `cache*` tables and the `system` table in my feature's row. Anyway, don't dive too deep into it, I know where I've used php field anyway :)

Comment: Good to know, I can stop giving people rubbish advice now thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some advantages of using templates instead of a custom PHP field.

1. Templates can be naturally version-controlled just like the rest of your code.  (You could version-control the custom php field with Features, but that is an additional layer of complexity.)
2. Since the code for templates is in files, you can use UNIX commands like grep, etc. to search them.  You can also batch edit them easily if necessary.
3. If you accidentally misconfigure your site permissions and give a role access to Views administration that shouldn't have it, they still won't be able to insert PHP into your site if you're using templates (eliminates a security risk).  Consider that one of the security enhancements in Drupal 7 over Drupal 6 was hiding the PHP filter and making it harder to enable.
4. The Views PHP module is still in dev and thus not subject to audit by the Drupal security team.  There may be (are) bugs in the module and since it is not in widespread use they may not be found for some time (avoids another security risk).

Yes, templates might be a little inconvenient, but from a security and maintainability standpoint I think they are clearly superior.

Comment: Good points. So you'd go for php field only if you needed sorting/filtering on that complex-to-produce output if I understand correctly.

Comment: If you need sorting/filtering, you can add a custom views handler.  There is no need to ever use the PHP field.

Comment: I wish I could upvote that comment 20 times

Comment: Can you provide some info/link to documentation on to how to implement such a feature?

Comment: Earl Miles, the creator of Views, has a book on Views and Panels development.  As for tutorials, here is one on custom filters: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-filters-views and another on exposed filters: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-make-range-selector-filter-views